# Multiple stacked charts on same page

Tags: amcharts

Figured this would be easy, but I'm missing something. Trying to add two stacked 100% charts to the same page. Data is being fed from MySQL via php. I know the php code is correct, since I am able to see correct data in the source code. Problem is, the second chart isn't showing up.

I have (I think) verified that the charts don't have any conflicting IDs. Here is the code for both charts:

Chart 1 (this one displays as expected):

```
<!-- Chart code -->
<script>
var ageChart = AmCharts.makeChart("agePie", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",

    "dataProvider": [{
        "demographic": "National",
        "18to34": 30.14,
        "35to54": 40.14,
        "55to64": 13.40,
        "65over": 16.32

    },
    {
        "demographic": "Segment",
        "18to34": <?php echo $age1Avg ?>,
        "35to54": <?php echo $age2Avg ?>,
        "55to64": <?php echo $age3Avg ?>,
        "65over": <?php echo $age4Avg ?> 

    }

    ],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "18-34",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "18to34"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "35-54",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "35to54"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "55-64",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "55to64"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[category]]:[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Over 65",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "65over"
    }],
    "marginTop": 30,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginBottom": 40,
    "autoMargins": false,
    "categoryField": "demographic",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }

});
</script>
```

Chart 2 (this one does NOT display). Should be the same configurations, just a different data comparison.

```
<script>
var ethChart = AmCharts.makeChart("ethPie", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",

    "dataProvider": [{
        "demographic2": "National",
        "Causacian": 30.14,
        "AfricanAmerican": 40.14,
        "Latin": 13.40,
        "Other": 16.32

    },
    {
        "demographic2": "Segment",
        "Causacian": <?php echo $eth1Avg ?>,
        "AfricanAmerican": <?php echo $eth2Avg ?>,
        "Latin": <?php echo $eth3Avg ?>,
        "Other": <?php echo $eth4Avg ?> 

    }

    ],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Caucasian",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Caucasian"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "African American",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "AfricanAmerican"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Latin",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Latin"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[category]]:[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Other",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Other"
    }],
    "marginTop": 30,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginBottom": 40,
    "autoMargins": false,
    "categoryField": "demographic2",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }

});
</script>
```

Calling each chart by the respective ID:

```
<div id="agePie"></div>
<div id="ethPie"></div>
```

Thoughts or shoves in the right direction?

Comment: Have you added CSS to define the dimensions for both charts?

Comment: I have for the first. I suppose I need to do that for the second as well! I'll give it a shot.

EDIT: just added style to the containers. Still issues, first div appears, second doesn't.

Comment: @Tim - Looks fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wzy7hgqy/). Can you post a fiddle with your code, data (after PHP rendered the page) and current css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please run the snippet below. Your code is working and it seems the lack of a defined dimension would be causing the issue.

I recommend you to try set a CSS class for both charts in case they should have the same dimension. Check the example below:

```
.chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

Add the class to both `DivElement`:

```
<div id="agePie" class="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="ethPie" class="chartdiv"></div>
```

Make sure you clean your browser cache. That could explain why you didn't see the difference before.

```js
var ageChart = AmCharts.makeChart("agePie", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",

    "dataProvider": [{
        "demographic": "National",
        "18to34": 30.14,
        "35to54": 40.14,
        "55to64": 13.40,
        "65over": 16.32

    },
    {
        "demographic": "Segment",
        "18to34": 24,
        "35to54": 40,
        "55to64": 60,
        "65over": 80 

    }

    ],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "18-34",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "18to34"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "35-54",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "35to54"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "55-64",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "55to64"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[category]]:[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Over 65",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "65over"
    }],
    "marginTop": 30,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginBottom": 40,
    "autoMargins": false,
    "categoryField": "demographic",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }

});


var ethChart = AmCharts.makeChart("ethPie", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",

    "dataProvider": [{
        "demographic2": "National",
        "Causacian": 30.14,
        "AfricanAmerican": 40.14,
        "Latin": 13.40,
        "Other": 16.32

    },
    {
        "demographic2": "Segment",
        "Causacian": 23,
        "AfricanAmerican": 34,
        "Latin": 12,
        "Other": 3 

    }

    ],
    "valueAxes": [{
        "stackType": "100%",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0,
        "labelsEnabled": false,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "graphs": [{
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Caucasian",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Caucasian"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "African American",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "AfricanAmerican"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[title]], [[category]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Latin",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Latin"
    }, {
        "balloonText": "[[category]]:[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px;'><b>[[value]]</b></span>",
        "fillAlphas": 0.9,
        "fontSize": 11,
        "labelText": "[[title]]: [[value]]%",
        "lineAlpha": 0.5,
        "title": "Other",
        "type": "column",
        "valueField": "Other"
    }],
    "marginTop": 30,
    "marginRight": 0,
    "marginLeft": 0,
    "marginBottom": 40,
    "autoMargins": false,
    "categoryField": "demographic2",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "gridPosition": "start",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "gridAlpha": 0
    }

});
```

```css
.chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="agePie" class="chartdiv"></div>
<div id="ethPie" class="chartdiv"></div>
```